# working with Adrotator in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to work with Adrotator?
i placed a Adrotator in my web application then i don't have any idea from here can u help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [How to use AdRotator control in ASP.Net](http://www.wwwcoder.com/parentid/261/tabid/68/type/art/site/5868/default.aspx)

You should create xml files like this

```
<Advertisements>

<Ad>
<ImageUrl>site1img1.jpg</ImageUrl>
<NavigateUrl>http://www.site1.com</NavigateUrl>
<AlternateText>Site1 Main</AlternateText>
<Impressions>50</Impressions>
<Keyword>Product1</Keyword>
</Ad>

<Ad>
<ImageUrl>site2img2.jpg</ImageUrl>
<NavigateUrl>http://www.site2.com</NavigateUrl>
<AlternateText>Site2 Main Page</AlternateText>
<Impressions>75</Impressions>
<Keyword>Product2</Keyword>
</Ad>

</Advertisements>
```

And add adrotator to your page like this

```
<asp:AdRotator id="AdRotator1"
   Target="_self"
   AdvertisementFile="myXmlFile.xml"
   runat="server"/>
```